# Up casting - c#

Tags: c#, .net, casting

```
public class a{
  public string x1 {get;set;}
  public string x2 {get;set;}
  public string x3 {get;set;}
}

public class b:a{
}
```

Obviously  `var foo = (b)new a();` will throw a casting error at runtime.

The only other way I can think to assign all the properties of an already instantiated and populated `a` is to manually copy each one over into a fresh instance of `b`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your question is about *downcasting*, your question title is about *upcasting*. – Which is correct?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: casting `a` to `b` is an 'upcast'

Comment: @Konrad Ah, i thought it was 'upcasting' seeing as I was casting 'a' to a 'higher' class.

Comment: @leppie No. Not according to common terminology, at least. See [Wikipedia: Downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) and [Java glossary: upcasting](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/upcasting.html).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: OK. Downcasting to me means casting to a less restrictive type.

Comment: @Heandel: To me, `b` is upwards in the hierarchy from `a`, but I guess this depends if you look at it as a tree or root system.

Comment: @Heandel: Given the lack of info on Wikipedia (no entry even for upcasting), I will just say, avoid both words, as they are prone to BS interpretation. A better wording would be: Type casting from parent to child type.

Comment: @Heandel: Fist time I ever seen that site :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of cast is wrong, because you can't cast parents to their children.
Type of `a` doesn't know about metainformation of type `b`. So you need provide the explicit cast operator to do such things, **but in this case you must remove inheritance**.
Other option is to define some interface, such as in other questions.

More information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: You are not allow to upcast via an explicit operator. The compiler will complain.

Comment: @VMAtm: 2 unrelated types are fine. But try a parent and child type. KABOOM!

Comment: Ooops. Didn't know. Thank you.

Comment: Neither upcasting nor downcasting uses a user-defined conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. Even if you think you have it, the compiler will complain.

This usually indicates a design or logical error.

Comment: @maxp: When 'you have it', implied creating a explicit cast operator, this WILL fail to compile.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that has always bothered me as well.
I worked out a solution to it by creating my own Up-Casting utility.

You can read my article here on how to do it -- it's pretty simple actually.

http://sympletech.com/c-up-casting-utility/

Answer (score 1):

You can't make that cast.

You can, and I guess you should, use an interface.

```
public interface ia
{
    string x1 { get; set; }
    string x2 { get; set; }
    string x3 { get; set; }
}
public class a : ia
{
    public string x1 { get; set; }
    public string x2 { get; set; }
    public string x3 { get; set; }
}

public class b : a, ia
{
}
```

Then you can

```
ia foo = new a();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your idea of creating a new instance of b and copying a's field values to it seems like an interesting approach. using reflection to achieve this should fit the bill nicely.

Something like: iterate through all of a's fields, get their values as stored in a and store them in the same field in b.

Still, this is not "downcasting" -- since it means a completely different object is created -- as opposed to reinterpreting the meaning of an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone's saying, it's not possible. Implicit casting is one solution, but I prefer to create a constructor on b that takes an instance of type a...

That way you can either: hold a reference to that a internally and delegate to it calls b inherits from a, or just simply copy the values out of the type a.