# C# Generic oddity

Tags: c#

Consider the following

```
public class MyBuilder {}

public interface IBuilder
{
    MyBuilder Builder { get; }
}

public class TestGeneric<B, S> where B : IBuilder, new()where S : MyBuilder
{
    public TestGeneric()
    {
        B b = new B();
        S s = b.Builder ;// as S;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyBuilder' to 'S'. An explicit
>   conversion exists...

Why not?
After all I'm clearly stating **S : MyBuilder**, it's a [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) class.

Also I don't think [Parameter Invariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx) applies here.
And [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333557/an-explicit-conversion-exists-are-you-missing-a-cast) question is similar but I don't see an answer as to why.
I'm using VS 2013 and .Net 4.5. and of course the cast works.

EDIT: I had a sealed class previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After all I'm clearly stating `S : MyBuilder`, it's a base class.

Yes, but you are trying to *upcast* the `MyBuilder` to `S` which will not work unless `S` *is* `MyBuilder`:

```
TestGeneric<IBuilderImpl,MyNewBuilder> g;
```

would try to cast `MyBuilder` to `MyNewBuilder` which would fail at runtime.

Comment: But isn't S : MyBuilder an 'is-a' relation? The compiler should not try to upcast here.If MyNewBuilder : MyBuilder your example should work just fine.

Comment: @narendra but `IBuilder.Builder` is a `MyBuilder` (not necessarily an `S`), so `S s = b.Builder` would upcast `MyBuilder` to `S`.

Comment: Ah! An IBuilder.MyBuilder is NOT a MyBuilder so an upcast will result. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting a the following error

> CS0701: 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

Comment: I has a sealed class previously.sry

Comment: I'm guessing that error will appear _after_ the invalid cast is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was not fully convinced so I continued to dig and harass colleagues!
Here is the answer [from MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

`For reference types, an explicit cast is required if you need to convert from a base type to a derived type`.

Which is precisely the case here, and as my colleague Alex pointed out:

`S inherits from MyBuilder, is not the same as "S.GetType() == typeof(MyBuilder)"`

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343301/up-casting-c-sharp) also verifies my assertion