# why this downcast fail in C#?

Tags: c#

i have a base class and derived class like below

```
 public class BaseClass
{
    public int No { set; get; }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

when i create instance of base class and want to downcast it to derived class it returns InvalidCastOperation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        BaseClass bas = new BaseClass();
        Derived derived = (Derived)bas; // invalid cast operation. why?
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

I am wondering why it does not work? and is a solution to implement this request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast

Comment: This should be called [*upcasting*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6343301/1997232).

Comment: All Derived are BaseClass but not all BaseClass are Derived

Comment: You are initializing Base class and trying to cast it to derived class. Base class do not have any information about the derived class and it do not have properties related to derived class too. So it can't be done. Derived class can be casted to base class but vice a versa is not possible. It would be better if you explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use more meaningful names:

```
class Fruit { }
class Apple : Fruit { public int PitCount; }

Fruit f = new Fruit(); // f is just some undetermined Fruity thing
Apple a = (Apple) f;   // why would it be an Apple? Where would PitCount come from?
```

The way to prevent some of this kind of errors is to make Fruit `abstract`.
A more common usage pattern, when `f` can come from various sources, is:

```
if (f is Apple)
{
    Apple a = (Apple) f; // now it will work
}
```

Comment: nice example. thanks to other friends for their response

Answer (score 9):

It's because you need to create an instance of `Derived` if you want to be able to cast back to it:

```
BaseClass bas = new Derived();
```

then you will be able to cast the `bas` instance (which is declared as `BaseClass` type) to the concrete `Derived` class that it is an instance of:

```
Derived derived = (Derived)bas;
```

Answer (score 6):

You created an instance of `BaseClass` and try to cast it to `Derived`. Of course it fails. Every `Derived` is also a `BaseClass`, but definitely not the other way around.

If you did

```
BaseClass bas = new Derived();
Derived derived = (Derived) bas;
```

it would work since the instance is *actually* an instance of `Derived`.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for inheritance are:

- Every instance of a derived class is also a instance of the base class
- The other way around does not apply. Not each base class is also one specific derived class. It could be simply an instance of the base class (like in your example), or an instance of another class which is derived from Base.

To fix your example:

```
BaseClass bas = new Derived();
Derived derived = (Derived)bas; // or better: = bas as Dervied
```

Comment: Why should `bas as Derived` be better in your view? We allready *know* `bas` actually is an instance of `Derived`, no need for a safe-cast and checking for `null`.

Comment: In this situation yes - it doesn't matter. It's only that I would in general prefer a safe cast (and type check) instead of simply an exception getting thrown.

Comment: Type-checking **and** safe-casting is useless, you´re better better be off using `as`-cast and check for `null` or if you really want the type-check then use direct-cast afterwards. But this is out of the scope of the question or this answer, just an aside.

Comment: That's what I meant. An as cast plus null check is a form of a type check for me. The `is` operator is another - depends on the situation what is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a base object to a derived type because the object is not of the derived type. The other way around works because a `DerivedType` object is also a `BaseType` by nature of inheritance. The reverse is not also true - a `BaseType` is not necessarily a `DerivedType`.

Think of it like this. You can do this:

```
Square a = new Square();
Shape b = (Shape)a;
```

because inheritance allows it to happen - a square *is* a shape.

However, trying to do this:

```
Shape a = new Shape();
Square b = (Square)a;
```

wouldn't work, because even though a square is a shape, the same can be said of a triangle, a circle, a parallelogram, or a trapezoid. It doesn't make sense to be able to take any random shape and say it can be *any* of those since that would be the same as saying that it is *all* of those, which is obviously not true - a square is not, and never will be, a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect when you write this:

```
object o = new object();
MyClass m = (MyClass) o;
```

Of course this fails as `o` is just an `object` without any knowledge on `MyClass`. In particular `o` doesn´t know how to set fields and properties defined in `MyClass`, so when creating `o` you can set just those members defined in `object`, not those for `MyClass`. Thus what would happen if the cast would succeed? You had an instance of `object` with just those members, cast it to `MyClass` and get an invalid instance of the latter as none of its members was initialized.

In other words: every instance of `MyClass` *is* an `object`, but of course not every `object` *is* a `MyClass`.

You have several opportunities.

1. Create an instance of your derived class

   ```
   BaseClass b = new Derived();
   ```
2. Create a copy-constructor that creates a new instance of `Derived` based on the current instance of `BaseClass`:

   ```
   public class BaseClass
   {
       public int MyProperty { get; set; }
   }

   public class Derived : BaseClass
   {
       public string AnotherProperty { get; set;}

       public Derived(BaseClass b)
       {
           this.MyProperty = b.MyProperty;
           this.AnotherProperty = "MyValue";
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use some reflction-based code that creates a new instance of `Derived` and copies all properties and fields from an existing instance of `BaseClass`. This is quite similar to 2. but avoids that you have to set the members yourself in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You `Derived` extends `BaseClass`.

You create `Basclass` with one attribute.

When you try casting it to `Derived` the attribute `Name` hasnt been created (so to speak)

If you were to try

```
 Derived derived = new Derived();
 BaseClass bas =(BaseClass)derived;
 System.Console.ReadLine();
```

it would work because derived extends base, so when derived is created it has both `Name` and `No` casting it to `BaseClass` effectively removes the `Name` variable.

Casting cannot add variables as you are trying to do. It expects it to be there, but its not.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why this fails is basically because your `Derived` **EXTENDS** your `BaseClass`. Meaning that it adds more (functionality, fields ... ) to it which is not present into your `BaseClass`. For this to work compiler would have to magically create a new instance that contains this extensions and then assign it to your field/variable.

Clearing things up. Whenever you're creating an instance of an object it creates all of the members inside of that type ( with base type metadata included ). And since your `BaseClass` was created as that type it does not know anything about `Derived`. Not mentioning nothing about new property introduced by your `Derived` object.

```
// BaseClass :
//  - metadata of this type and System.Object ( because every object derives from System.Object in C# )
//  - field info of "No" property's backing field 
//  - property info "No" property

// Derived :
//  - metadata of this type and BaseClass type
//  - field info of "Name" property's backing field 
//  - property info "Name" property
```